# How will chromium remove manifest v2 & add v1

Tags: chromium

Since Chromium will remove manifest v2 in 2024, i want to fork chromium and make it to support v2. One will have to manually install it though, not available on the store anymore. What files will chromium change/edit to remove support for manifest v2? Also, how will I add Manifest v1 back?

I searched for manifest in the chromium mirror, but no useful results came up.

Comment: The answer to your question will be very broad. You should get familiar with Chromium code and start searching/debugging it's code.

Comment: I have tried doing that, @asesh. However, I want to know where those files are located.